# BoundedBlockingQueue Java

Tags: java, concurrency, priority-queue, java-7, akka

I am looking for a `BoundedBlockingQueue` that can take any other `Queue` and make it bounded and blocking.

I found `akka.util.BoundedBlockingQueue` which can do that, but the source code has some fixmes in it. So I'm not sure it's clever to use the code.

At the end I want to have a PriorityQueue bounded and useable for concurrent use.

Are there some other classes that I can use for this task? Maybe in Java 7?

Comment: Will the wrapped queue be accessed through **only** this blocking queue?

Comment: Yes, the real queue can be totally isolated.

Comment: An interesting problem.  It would have been nice if the ArrayBlockingQueue inherited an abstract BoundedBlockingQueue class which forced the overriding of insert and extract methods.  An there is nothing in Java 7 coming that would support this.

Comment: If the PriorityQueue is isolated, how are you going to change it so it is bounded, wrapping the queue won't make the original queue bounded.

Comment: Why not? If the wrapper is the only access to the queue, then the wrapper can do a size check and then call wait. I don't see why that shouldn't work.

Comment: It could be done, you just need to maintain the size vs capacity. And handle the locking/signaling yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The akka BoundedBlockingQueue seems to be pretty ok for me ([Source code](http://codesearch.google.com/#as1_5zaInWM/akka-actor/src/main/&q=akka.util.BoundedBlockingQueue)). I would really consider using it (at least after writing a good set of unit tests for the class because tests for this class are missing in akka)

The FIXMEs are in pretty strange situations like calling removeAll on the backing queue and it is not empty after that, which is simply a very bad error in the implementation of the backing queue class.

I have not understood what you mean with *"the code doesn't let me make the constructor generic"*.

Comment: That works, I was just trying to have the queue as the generic parameter, but you only need the object that you're using...

Comment: Since you looked at the code. Normally put can throw a interrupted exception. But somehow the code swallows that?

Comment: await will throw an interrupted exception when it is interrupted. awaitUninterruptibly is a non-interruptable version. However please note that I look at the Scala version of it. I have not found a Java version.

Comment: The code isn't in GIT so google doesnt find it. But you can find it here http://akka.io/downloads/ . But I think it will be the same as the scala stuff.

Comment: I've talked to Doug (Lea) about adding something similar for jsr166(something)